# Multisite favicon.ico

Tags: multisite, favicon

I know it's pretty easy to add a unique favicon.ico to each site in a multisite install. But any ideas for making each sites favicon.ico appear to be in the root directory of the site?

The end result would be http://example.com/favicon.ico and http://anotherexample.com/favicon.ico

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are using different theme in each site

Just add this code in your header.php file.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" />
```

Add your favicon in each theme.

### For favicon in admin area.

Add the following function in your function.php file.

```
function admin_favicon() { ?> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" /> <?php } 
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_favicon');
```

Comment: :I have the same issue. i did as you said it works fain in front end but not working in backend any idea

Comment: @gowri Updated my answer